# Weird Ruby on Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I ran `bundle install` and then `rails s` the other day and got the following error:

```
/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/gems/activerecord-1.6.0/lib/active_record/support/clean_logger.rb:5:in `remove_const': constant Logger::Format not defined (NameError)
```

I've read I can fix this by going into the `clean_logger.rb` file and commenting out that line, but I've never touched that file and I don't want to edit it if I can help it.  Does anybody know what this file does or how I can fix this?  I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.0.rc4.

**Update**

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Asset template engines
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

# JavaScript
gem 'jquery-rails'

# CSS
gem 'compass', :git => "https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git", :branch => "rails31"

# Authentication
gem 'authlogic'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# pagination
gem 'will_paginate'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'annotate-models'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'#, :require => (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i)
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'word_salad'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :deployment do
  gem 'heroku'
end
```

**Update 2**

As per the requests in the comments:

.rvmrc

```
(empty)
```

`rvm info`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Big.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.6.20 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p180"
    date:         "2011-02-18"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.7.0"
    patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 revision 30909"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31"
    ruby:         "/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/bin:/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/helixed/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31:/Users/helixed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/helixed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "rails31"
```

`gem list`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.0.rc4, 0.6.1)
actionpack (3.1.0.rc4)
activemodel (3.1.0.rc4)
activerecord (3.1.0.rc4, 1.6.0)
activeresource (3.1.0.rc4)
activesupport (3.1.0.rc4)
annotate-models (1.0.4)
ansi (1.2.5)
arel (2.1.1)
authlogic (3.0.3, 2.1.6)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
blueprint-rails (0.1.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.15)
chunky_png (1.2.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.1)
compass (0.11.3)
compass-960-plugin (0.10.4)
configuration (1.3.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.0)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
faker (0.9.5)
fssm (0.2.7)
guard (0.4.2)
guard-rspec (0.4.0)
heroku (2.3.4, 2.3.3)
hike (1.1.0)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.12, 1.0.11)
launchy (0.4.0)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
nokogiri (1.4.6)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.3.0)
rack-cache (1.0.2)
rack-mount (0.8.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.0)
rails (3.1.0.rc4, 0.9.5)
railties (3.1.0.rc4)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rb-fsevent (0.4.0)
rdoc (3.6.1)
rest-client (1.6.3)
rspec (2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
sass (3.1.3)
sass-rails (3.1.0.rc.3, 3.1.0.rc.2)
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.10)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.2)
treetop (1.4.9)
turn (0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.28)
uglifier (1.0.0, 0.5.4)
webrat (0.7.3)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
word_salad (2.0.0)
```

Comment: why are you using `activerecord 1.6`? can you upgrade it?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  I've never fully figured out RVM.  I actually don't understand why I can't just use the Gemfile for everything, and install the things I want per project.  When I installed rails, I created a new gemset in RVM, and then install the latest Rails on top of it.  What do I need to do to upgrade?

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting the exact same error

Comment: Please provide your project's `.rvmrc` file contents and the output from the commands `rvm info` and `gem list` (both from in your project directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you are installing an ancient version of activerecord which is failing.

What I would do is first check your `Gemfile.lock` file to see what gem is specifying an old version of activerecord. (Do a search in that file.) If you can, comment out that gem which uses the old activerecord from the Gemfile or use a more modern version or replacement of that gem if you need it. (Nothing jumps out at me from a cursory examination of your Gemfile, maybe you installed some old stuff earlier and removed it?)

If you don't see version 1.6 of activerecord specified in the `Gemfile.lock`, I'd blow up your rvm gemset and install again from the command line. You probably have some old stuff in there for whatever reason. In your project directory use the following commands:

```
$ rvm gemset empty rails31

$ rvm gemset use rails31

$ gem install bundler

$ bundle install
```

Good luck!

Comment: It worked!  You were right; my `Gemfile.lock` has 1.6 specified.  I went ahead and deleted it and then (just for good measure) wiped out my rvm gemset too.  Now it works perfectly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, I'd also nuke your `Gemfile.lock`, and specify which version of Rails you're using in your Gemfile:

```
gem "rails", "3.1.0.rc4"
```

And then re-bundle everything by running `bundle`