# activerecord-jdbc-adapter requires ActiveRecord at runtime error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, jruby

So i just updated the JRUBY to 1.7.3 [1.9] and did a fresh gem install for the 1.9 version of ruby.

Here are the versions of my activerecord gems:

```
activerecord (1.6.0)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.9)
ActiveRecord-JDBC (0.5)
activesupport (3.2.13)
```

When i try to execute a database statement i get the following error

```
activerecord-jdbc-adapter requires ActiveRecord at runtime
no such file to load -- active_record/version (LoadError)
```

anyone know what's going on?  I have verified by using `jgem list` that these gems are all installed

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ActiveRecord-JDBC (0.5)
    Ascii85 (1.0.2)
    activerecord (1.6.0)
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.9)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    afm (0.2.0)
    akami (1.2.0)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
    builder (3.2.0)
    business_time (0.6.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.31)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    cucumber (1.2.3)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.11.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    cuke_sniffer (0.0.3)
      roxml
    data_magic (0.14)
      faker (>= 1.1.2)
      yml_reader (>= 0.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.1)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.6.0)
    gherkin (2.11.6-java)
      json (>= 1.7.6)
    gyoku (1.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    hashery (2.1.0)
    httpi (2.0.2)
      rack
    i18n (0.6.1)
    jruby-openssl (0.8.7)
      bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0147)
    jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
    json (1.7.7-java)
    mime-types (1.21)
    multi_json (1.7.2)
    nokogiri (1.5.9-java)
    nori (2.0.4)
    page-object (0.8.6.1)
      page_navigation (>= 0.7)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 2.31.0)
      watir-webdriver (>= 0.6.2)
    page_navigation (0.7)
      data_magic (>= 0.14)
    pdf-reader (1.3.2)
      Ascii85 (~> 1.0.0)
      afm (~> 0.2.0)
      hashery (~> 2.0)
      ruby-rc4
      ttfunk
    rack (1.5.2)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rautomation (0.8.0)
      ffi
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    roxml (3.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
    rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.0)
    ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    ruby-ole (1.2.11.6)
    ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    savon (2.1.0)
      akami (~> 1.2.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (~> 1.0.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
      nori (~> 2.0.3)
      wasabi (~> 3.0.0)
    selenium-webdriver (2.31.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    sources (0.0.1)
    spreadsheet (0.8.3)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    ttfunk (1.0.3)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    wasabi (3.0.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 2.18.0)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yml_reader (0.2)

PLATFORMS
  java

DEPENDENCIES
  ActiveRecord-JDBC
  activerecord
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter
  builder
  business_time
  childprocess
  cucumber
  cuke_sniffer
  ffi
  gherkin
  jruby-openssl
  jruby-win32ole
  json
  mime-types
  nokogiri
  page-object
  pdf-reader
  rake
  rautomation
  rest-client
  rspec
  ruby-debug-ide
  rubyzip
  savon
  selenium-webdriver
  sources
  spreadsheet
  watir-webdriver
  xpath
```

Comment: missing bundler or an include of rubygems?

Comment: ok, I changed the order in the require statement to see if that can be an issue, and I got another error in the active_record gem  `constant Format not defined for Logger (NameError) org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2648:in remove_const`

Comment: well it looks like its finding ActiveRecord now. What logger are you using?

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496848/weird-ruby-on-rails-error this is because your using an old version of AR

Comment: @j_mcnally bundler ran successfully.  top of bundler file `source 'http://rubygems.org'`

Comment: try forcing a newer AR version or removing / updating your lock file

Comment: this is a known issue in AR 1.6.0

Comment: @j_mcnally I removed the lock file and did an install again.  It still installed 1.6.0.   I updated the question with my gemlock file

Comment: ok in your Gemfile can you say `gem "activerecord", "~> 3.2.13"`

Comment: thats wierd.... hmmm... you could try adding `gem "builder", "~> 3.0.0"`

Comment: yes it works fine, I just forgot to delete my lock file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue was your require statement,

Your second issue was using 1.6.0 which has been reported to throw this error. The solution is to remove AR 1.6.0 from your Gemfile.lock and install a newer version.

In your Gemfile add:

```
gem "activerecord", "~> 3.2.13"
```

then re-run bundler after fixing your Gemfile.lock

Comment: I'm not specifying my activerecord version in the gemfile (gem 'activerecord') however it seems to install that version.  I've included my lock file so you can see if I'm missing a dependancy somewhere